# C++ - Bit shifting returning negative numbers

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I'm having some trouble trying to use bit shifting in C++.

I have a `char a = 160`, and `char b = 0`. The value of a is `0b10100000`. I want to shift the leftmost bits of `a` into `b`, so that `b` would have the value 2 (0b10). By my logic, this should do it:

```
b = (b << 2) | (a >> 6);
```

However, when I check the value in b, it's `-2` and not `2`, as I would expect it to be. Casting it to an `unsigned char` changes it's value to 254.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(b << 2)` is totally unnecessary if `b==0`; what happens if you just `char b= a >> 6;`?

Comment: `char` --> `unsigned char`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Was thinking exactly the same, but I don't know any machine where integers would have a zero highest bit describe a negative number

Comment: Probably your `char a = 160` is not really 160, but something like -96 (hint: if char are signed the maximum value is 127, and 160 is past this limit).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ah nevermind, I'm stupid; 160 of course has the highest bit set to one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both types must be unsigned:

```
unsigned char a = 160;
unsigned char b = 0;
b = (b << 2) | (a >> 6);
```

is exactly the same as:

```
unsigned char c = a >> 6;
```